# Why Symfony framework is able to use comment out area to identify entity file?

Tags: php, symfony, comments

Could anyone tell me how does Symfony framework use comment out the area to do something? I'm a quite junior developer, before using Symfony, I have never seen any syntax like this.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
```

or

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/products/add_favorite/{id}", name="product_add_favorite", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 */
```

I know `/*......*/` is an area to comment out and used to define a function before it. But why it comes functionality here, Hope you can tell me where do I miss.

Comment: Basically, Symfony uses a package from Doctrine to read these annotations. Annotations are multiline comment blocks that start with `/**` as opposed to `/*` like regular comments. See more info following the links in the dupe answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Symfony you have the option to use annotation, xml or yml configuration.'
By default the annotation is used, that's what you see in this case.
Personally I think it's a nice way to get your configuration close to the actual code which it affects to.

More info, see this [blog](https://www.sitepoint.com/your-own-custom-annotations/)